# How to use celery with multiple databases?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-database, celerybeat

I am moving my django project from single database to using 2 different mysql databases(master-slave configuration), where all my reads go to the slave, and writes go to the master.

I have following configurations in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {},
'master': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': config('django.db.dbName'),
    'USER': config('django.db.dbUser'),
    'PASSWORD': config('django.db.dbPass'),
    'HOST': config('django.db.dbhost_master'),
},
'slave': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': config('django.db.dbUser'),
    'USER': config('credential_id'),
    'PASSWORD': config('dbPass'),
    'HOST': config('django.db.dbhost_slave'),
},
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["db_router.DBRouter"]
```

And this is what my DBRouter looks like:

```
class DBRouter(object):
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Reads always go to the slave.
    """
    return 'slave'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Writes always go to the master.
    """
    return 'master'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
    in the master/replica nodes.
    """
    db_list = ('master', 'slave')
    if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
        return True

    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    All non-auth models end up in this pool.
    """
    return True
```

I faced some issues with running migration, but everything works fine, when I provide **--database=master** explicitly with each command:

Eg. venv/bin/python app/manage.py migrate --database=master --no-input;

But I am unable to start celerybeat with this configuration.

```
python manage.py celerybeat --settings="com_executor.settings" --logfile=~/celery_beat.log
```

gives an error:
    ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

This is the same error, I get while migrating but goes away once I add --database=master.

But the same doesn't work in case of celerybeat:

```
python manage.py celerybeat --database=master --settings="com_executor.settings" --logfile=~/celery_beat.log
```

Gives below error

```
manage.py celerybeat: error: unrecognized arguments: --database=master
```

Has anyone found any way to handle such scenario, or adding a "default" configuration for the database is the only way to get it work? (which I want to avoid as far as possible, to make sure that I am not sending unexpected commands to the wrong DB instance)

Comment: Maybe you can try giving your master or slave in default ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing as a workaround. But want to avoid that, as mentioned at the end of the question.

Because that way any flow in which I miss out to specify database will also silently go to "default"(in my case, I have copied slave config in "default"). While without "default", such mistakes result in a failure, and I get to fix the same.

By just keeping 'master' & 'slave' configs, I can be sure that any request that reaches the database, goes through DB router only, and gets filtered for read & write.

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I am facing the same issue and adding a db to default is not an option.